# Visual Studio 6.0 apps on Azure

Tags: azure, vb6, legacy, visual-c++-6

Can I run apps created by Visual Studio 6 on Azure? Im thinking of already compiled legacy ones that give console output that can be piped. What are my options?

Apps are written in Both visual Basic and visual C++ 6.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you mean Visual *Basic* 6.0 applications, then yes, deploy a Virtual Machine with [any of these OSes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-basic-6/visual-basic-6-support-policy?redirectedfrom=MSDN) and run your application on it.

> The Visual Basic team is committed to "It Just Works" compatibility for Visual Basic 6.0 applications on the following supported Windows operating systems:

> ```
> Windows 10
> Windows 8.1
> Windows 7
> Windows Server 2019
> Windows Server 2016
> Windows Server 2012 including R2
> Windows Server 2008 including R2
> ```
>
> The Visual Basic team’s goal is that Visual Basic 6.0 applications continue to run on supported Windows versions. As detailed in this document, the core Visual Basic 6.0 runtime will be supported for the full lifetime of supported Windows versions [...]

(From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-basic-6/visual-basic-6-support-policy)

You can probably use [Azure Container Instances](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/container-instances/) as well with Windows containers, but building a container image for VB6 may be tricky.